# Is there a way to print cron-expressions in human readable form?

Tags: java, logging, cron, lib

Is there some way in java, a library or similar to interpret a cron-expression to human-readable format? I was thinking using it to log how often a job is run to potentially spot wrong cron-expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use cron-parser:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.redhogs.cronparser</groupId>
    <artifactId>cron-parser</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, you can use the CronExpressionDescriptor class to get human-readable descriptions e.g. `CronExpressionDescriptor.getDescription("46 9 * * 1")` gives "*At 9:46 AM, only on Monday*".

refs:

https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/net.redhogs.cronparser/cron-parser/3.5
https://github.com/grahamar/cron-parser
https://github.com/grahamar/cron-parser/blob/master/cron-parser-core/src/test/java/net/redhogs/cronparser/CronExpressionDescriptorTest.java (contains comprehensive usage cases)

Comment: Thanks. I also found this one https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils